# Installing Mosquitto with Busybox

Tags: mqtt, busybox, mosquitto

I'm trying to put a Mosquitto client onto a small monitoring server that uses busybox on a linux machine. I've unzipped the mosquitto tar file. But because I only have busybox I don't have apt-get, aptitude, make, cmake, dbuild, makepkg, pacman to finish the install.

Any ideas?

Comment: Figured out that OEM of the device didn't include any packages nor any busybox commands that could be used to compile Mosquitto nor anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it doesn't have some other package management system (and a mosquitto package) then the usual solution to problems like this is to compile mosquitto on a different machine with all the required tools then just copy the binaries only.

You've not said what architecture the target machine is but you normally don't even need it to be the same as the build machine as you can cross-compile binaries for different platforms.

Comment: I'm working with an embedded system produced by an OEM. Even though I could get a "make" package(?) on to the device I couldn't open it. I've managed to figure out that the manufacturer did not include the dpkg nor rpm commands in busybox. The OEM really doesn't want me playing around with their design.

Comment: For posterity:

logged into busybox, do a dmesg or uname -a to get the kernel and GCC versions.  that may be a good place to start for trying to cross-compile elsewhere for use on the system.